# Differences between network protocol TCP/UDP/ICMP

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

I have a question about network protocols. When I'm receiving packets to decode it how I can determine if its TCP or UDP or ICMP?

Is there any sign of byte number can I use it to know?

Comment: I think that depends greatly on which protocols are being used in the different layers. For instance, in layer-4, UDP would have less overhead than TCP, It will also depend on the OS and network stack.

Comment: @Hani If you're using the TCP protocol, why are you asking the question? Your're receiving TCP, period. You aren't even receiving packets, just a byte stream. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP, the original question was very different, but it was edited.

Comment: @RonMaupin I don't see what that has to do with it. My comment refers to the question as it was at the time I posted it, and it had been in that state for a couple of hours.

Comment: @EJP, I just meant that the OP's comment about using TCP was made on the original question, where it made more sense. It doesn't make sense in the new, completely different question. I really think a new question should have been asked, rather having the question edited to something which doesn't resemble the original.

Comment: yeah i'm sorry for confusing

Answer (score 0):

The IPv4 packet header has a Protocol field which tells you which protocol is in the packet payload.

With IPv6 it is a little more complex. The IPv6 packet Next Header field will tell you the same thing if there are no IPv6 extension headers. If there are IPv6 extension headers, you will need to follow the chain of headers to get the last header in order to determine the payload type.

Comment: I use IPv4 but I have multiple packet to figure out if they TCP Or UDP

Comment: How I can know the difference? is there any stable number for mac address, source .etc ? thank u

Comment: You seem to be greatly confused. MAC addresses are layer-2 addresses, and they only exist in layer-2 frames, where there is an EtherType field to tell you which layer-3 protocol is in the layer-3 packet. An IP (one of the layer-3 protocols) packet would be the payload of a layer-2 frame, and it has the Protocol field which tells you which layer-4 protocol is in the layer-4 segment. A TCP, UDP, ICMP, etc. (layer-4 protocol) segment is the payload of a layer-3 packet. You need to learn about OSI layers, the headers for each type, and how one layer encapsulates the next layer.

Comment: but what if I have packet like that

Comment: 4500 003a 45644000 4006 df05 0a01 
012b 0a01 0128 bfcf 3a98 e938 b9c8 e8a0 761f 8018 05b4 ef33 0000 0101 080a 0005 ff310005 2c31 6865 6c6c 6f0a

Comment: how i can determine if its use tcp or udp or icmp ..etc ?

Comment: @Hani, I don't understand. If you have a packet, you look in the packet header to see what the Protocol field has in it. It will tell you which layer-4 protocol (TCP, UDP, etc.) is in the packet payload. You then need to look at the segment header with the correct routine for that protocol. You need to learn how to read the headers for the various protocols and learn how to walk the layers. This is freely available information, but the best sources are the RFCs which define the protocols. Just do an Internet search.

Comment: thank u so much yes i'm really confusing also I search before but i don't find anything about how to read packet and anaysis

Comment: is there any value in packet header guide me if its TCP or UDP?

Comment: The 10th octet is the Protocol field, but you need to understand the rest of the header fields, too. For instance, you really want to know if it is IPv4 or IPv6 since they have different header formats, and the IP version is in the header. I assume you will also want to determine where the layer-4 protocol starts, and you find that in the packet header. You should also learn how to use the CRC for IPv4 to determine if the packet is even good. Start with RFC 760, just search for it.

Comment: It doesn't matter what your field of study is. If you are given an IP packet, you need to tell which IP version it is since you don't want to try to apply your IPv4 routines to an IPv6 packet. That would result in garbage.